# My tooth wont stay and all my other ones are :s

Tags: weight-painting

I am making a nutcracker. I joined all the teeth to the face. I weight painted them all also because they weren't sticking with the bone. All of them moved with the head and the bone which is what I wanted. But one problem was just one tooth did not want to stay put. After joining and weight painting, why is this still a issue?

[image]

Comment: Select each of the bones and make sure that the tooth hasn't had a weight accidentally applied to them as well.

Comment: An easy way to make sure is to check the box of "Auto Normalize" in the brush options under Weight, Raius, Strength, Blend. and then paint over the tooth again.